# If the no. of threads should be double of no. cores, then why in 12th gen laptops there are 12cores and 16 threads?

Tags: multithreading

I have to buy laptop for programming and I searching for a good, but can't decide due to no. of different cores and threads combination in every brand laptop of 12th intel processors, some are having 10cores and 12threads combination and 12cores and 16threads. Which one should I go for?

Comment: https://www.howtogeek.com/767730/what-are-p-cores-and-e-cores-on-an-intel-cpu/

Answer (score 3):

12th-gen Intel CPUs come equipped with two types of cores, performance cores *(P-cores)* and "economic" cores *(E-cores)*.  P-cores support two threads per core, while E-cores support only one thread and run at a lower clock speed (the idea is to be more energy efficient by scheduling background and low priority tasks on these E-cores).

For instance, the i7-12700K supports 8 performance cores and 4 e-cores, for a total of 20 threads (2 x 8) + 4.

If budget is of concern, try to look for the sweet spot between price and performance. I've read that at this particular moment, the i5 is the one filling that spot.